# NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Adding to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, null, modal-dialog, nullreferenceexception

I get an error whenever I try to add a new a object to my model I get this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Not sure why as I always create a new object.

I have a Model which consist of:

```
public class Model
{
    public IList<Model1> Something { get; set; }
    public IList<Model2> Something1 { get; set; }
}
```

I also have in my controller:

```
        Model model = new Model();

        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Login"];
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            int ID = int.Parse(cookie["ID"]);

            var DBInfo = db.Details(ID);
            foreach (var info in DBInfo)
            {
                Something1 model1 = new Something1();
                model1.ID = ID;
                model1.FullName = info.FullName;
                model1.CourseCode = info.CourseCode;
                model.Something1.Add(model1);

            }
```

The error pops up when I am adding this model1 to model

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: I did see that but coudln't unserstand why my code made the error as I thought I was creating a new object using this line "Something1 model1 = new Something1();", but it seems I have to create a new list to add the object which is something I did not realise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must initialize `Something1` field before use, like this:

```
model.Something1 = new List<Model2>();
```

Or, when init Model:

```
Model model = new Model
{
    Something = new List<Model1>(),
    Something1 = new List<Model2>()
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was initializing this when calling "Something1 model1 = new Something1();"